# How to generate array of long from wsdl?

Tags: java, wsdl

I am using following type to generate web service response class:

```
        <xsd:complexType name="SaveUniversalIdsRequest">
           <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="persist" type="mu:UniversalIdList" />
              <xsd:element name="remove" type="xsd:long" />
              <xsd:element name="secString" type="xsd:string" />
           </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

And it generates a class with
   protected long remove;

But i want to generate an array instead. Adding  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" generates a List.

Please, assist.

Comment: If you get List, consider 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

As you can find this :
[What is the WSDL declaration for an array of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054184/what-is-the-wsdl-declaration-for-an-array-of-integers)

```
<element name="ArrayOfLongs">
 <complexType>
  <sequence>
   <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="remove" type="xsd:long"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
</element>
```

Comment: This will generate a list of long instead of a long array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jaxb customized bindings feature - [Customizing XML Schema-to-Java Mapping Using Binding Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html)

try with the following command:

**wsimport -verbose -b jaxbindings.xml -keep -Xnocompile -p com.vmware.vim25 -s "src" vimService.wsdl**

The content of the jaxbingdings.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     jaxb:version="2.1"
     xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
       <jaxb:globalBindings
           collectionType ="indexed"
           generateIsSetMethod="false">
       </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Note the collectionType should be indexed. you can also set this to your own definied list like com.my.List.